# Does iOS watchdog monitor process while debugger is attached?

Tags: ios, networking

I'm debugging a background task issue where my app is being killed by the watchdog when socket data is received too often in the background.

Does the watchdog perform it's operations under the context of a debugger?

My answer is: I do not believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some logs I have seen about apps failing to respond for 10 seconds while paused in the debugger, I would say yes it is watching, but it does not enforce its rules.  It simply informs you.